# why null value display in actionbar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, null

[image]

I am making simple demo of tab view .But on first line i am getting null pointer exception . I am getting null value from this method **`getActionBar()`** why ?
I will share you my class

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
   ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar=getActionBar(); /// <- this is the line causing issue
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    }
    // ---------- methods ---------------//
}
```

I get null value on the line  **`actionBar=getActionBar();`**

here is my manifest file and style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**app.grudle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.naveen.tabviewswipe"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to extend FragmentActivity, then you need to use non-appcompat theme i.e. Holo to get actionbar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainActivity` needs to extend `AppCompatActivity` (instead of `FragmentActivity`). Also, you'll need to use a different method to get the `ActionBar`:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
```

This is because you're using the support library.

Comment: it is not showing getsupportbat method ..please check my update

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` inheriting `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: but action bar activity is depricated ..I am getting the result using actionbar .but when I am using this AppCompatActivity ..still  i am getting null .I am getting the correct result using actionbaractivity but it is depricated

Comment: Yes, inheriting `AppCompatActivity` is correct (it was added in version 22.1.0 of the support library, replacing `ActionBarActivity`). Both are equivalent though. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should extends `ActionBarActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar()`.